# Binomial Confidence Intervals - Bayes Jeffrey's Prior vs Agresti-Coull method

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval

The R binom library has several confidence intervals to choose from for Binomial distributions.

The Bayes method uses the Beta distribution. According to the binom documentation:

The default prior is Jeffrey's prior which is a Beta(0.5, 0.5) distribution. Thus the posterior mean is ***(x + 0.5)/(n + 1)***.

```
p|x ~ Beta(x + prior.shape1, n - x + prior.shape2)
```

The prior.shape1 and prior.shape2 can be passed in like so:

```
binom.bayes(x, n,
            conf.level = 0.95,
            type = c("highest", "central"),
            prior.shape1 = 0.5,
            prior.shape2 = 0.5,
            tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5,
            maxit = 1000, ...)
```

Remembering that the default Bayes formula is (x + 0.5)/(n + 1), what would the shape parameters be to replicate Agresti Coull? (So instead of 0.5 and 1, they'd be replaced with **1/2*z^2** and **z^2** respectively.)

**Question #1, what would the shape1 and shape2 parameters of the Beta distribution be to match Agresti Coull?**

[image: Agresti Coull]

Academically, Agresti-Coull confidence interval is considered a Bayesian method.
The Agresti-Coull Interval specifies prior knowledge of z^2 for typically 3.8416 or essentially 4 given the rule of thumb "add 2 successes and 2 failures".

So for this analysis, I put ***z=2***.  Notice that the Agresti-Coull more closely matches the "exact" method than does Bayes set to Jeffrey's Prior ***(shape1,shape2)=(1/2,1/2)***.

If one notices the ***w=*** values, those are the necessary weight to replicate the "exact" method as per Agresti-Coull method. (***w=z^2***)

**UPDATE ON QUESTION #1**

Looking at the source code for binom.bayes, one sees:

```
a <- x + prior.shape1
b <- n - x + prior.shape2
p <- a/(a + b)
```

Where p is the suggested mean given by the method.
Expanding p, we get

```
p <- (x + prior.shape1) / (n + prior.shape1 + prior.shape2)
```

Notice that the x cancels out in the denominator.

That implies that `prior.shape1 <- prior.shape2 <- (z^2)/2` as a possibility.

Given

```
ptilde=function(x,n,z=2){
  n=n+z*z
  p=1/n*(x+0.5*z*z)
  p
}
```

we get:

```
> binom.bayes(0,25,prior.shape1 = (qnorm(0.95+.05/2)^2)/2,prior.shape2 = (qnorm(0.95+.05/2)^2)/2)
  method x  n   shape1   shape2       mean lower     upper  sig
1  bayes 0 25 1.920729 26.92073 0.06659613     0 0.1551559 0.05
> binom.agresti.coull(0,25)
         method x  n mean       lower     upper
1 agresti-coull 0 25    0 -0.02439494 0.1575872
> ptilde(0,25,(qnorm(0.95+.05/2)))
[1] 0.06659613
```

Notice the mean are identical (the output from ptilde) As an aside, I do not know why binom.agresti.coull doesn't report the new mean??  I calculated as per the Wikipedia article.

At least as compared to the "exact" method and N=25, binom.bayes with the Agresti-Coull shape appears better.  Any thoughts on this?

---

Question 2 follows:

```
require(binom)
ans0=c()
ans1=c()
for(n in (1:50)){ 
  for(x in c(0,n)){
    b=binom.exact(x,n); 
    bayes=binom.bayes(x,n)
    clevel=1-pnorm(2,lower.tail = F)*2 
    z=2
    n.tilde=n+z^2
    p.tilde=1/n.tilde*(x+1/2*z^2) #see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval
    m=mean(c(b$lower,b$upper));
    w=(m*n-x)/(0.5-m)
    check=(w  *0.5+x)/(w+n)
    cat(x,'/',n,' "exact".center=',m,' bayes.mean=',bayes$mean,' ac.mean=',p.tilde,' w=',w,' weighted.avg=',check,"\n")
    if(x==0) {
      ans0[n]=w;
    }else {
      ans1[n]=w;
    }
  }
}
View(data.frame(xEq0=ans0,xEq1=ans1))
```

Output:

```
0 / 1  "exact".center= 0.4875  bayes.mean= 0.25  ac.mean= 0.4  w= 39  weighted.avg= 0.4875 
0 / 2  "exact".center= 0.4209431  bayes.mean= 0.1666667  ac.mean= 0.3333333  w= 10.64911  weighted.avg= 0.4209431 
0 / 3  "exact".center= 0.3537991  bayes.mean= 0.125  ac.mean= 0.2857143  w= 7.259856  weighted.avg= 0.3537991 
0 / 4  "exact".center= 0.3011823  bayes.mean= 0.1  ac.mean= 0.25  w= 6.059467  weighted.avg= 0.3011823 
0 / 5  "exact".center= 0.2609119  bayes.mean= 0.08333333  ac.mean= 0.2222222  w= 5.456396  weighted.avg= 0.2609119 
0 / 6  "exact".center= 0.2296291  bayes.mean= 0.07142857  ac.mean= 0.2  w= 5.095867  weighted.avg= 0.2296291 
0 / 7  "exact".center= 0.2048082  bayes.mean= 0.0625  ac.mean= 0.1818182  w= 4.856698  weighted.avg= 0.2048082 
0 / 8  "exact".center= 0.1847083  bayes.mean= 0.05555556  ac.mean= 0.1666667  w= 4.686665  weighted.avg= 0.1847083 
0 / 9  "exact".center= 0.1681336  bayes.mean= 0.05  ac.mean= 0.1538462  w= 4.559672  weighted.avg= 0.1681336 
0 / 10  "exact".center= 0.1542486  bayes.mean= 0.04545455  ac.mean= 0.1428571  w= 4.461255  weighted.avg= 0.1542486 
0 / 11  "exact".center= 0.1424571  bayes.mean= 0.04166667  ac.mean= 0.1333333  w= 4.382768  weighted.avg= 0.1424571 
0 / 12  "exact".center= 0.1323242  bayes.mean= 0.03846154  ac.mean= 0.125  w= 4.318726  weighted.avg= 0.1323242 
0 / 13  "exact".center= 0.1235263  bayes.mean= 0.03571429  ac.mean= 0.1176471  w= 4.265483  weighted.avg= 0.1235263 
0 / 14  "exact".center= 0.1158179  bayes.mean= 0.03333333  ac.mean= 0.1111111  w= 4.220525  weighted.avg= 0.1158179
```

**Question #2** For small values of the ideal weight parameter may be as high as 39.  Would it be best to modify Agresti-Coull to adjust it's method of weight to match accordingly?

**References:**

[Agresti-Coull Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval)

Comment: http://www.obscureanalytics.com/2012/07/04/to-the-basics-bayesian-inference-on-a-binomial-proportion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1:
Setting $Z = 1$ with the Agresti Coull method will yield the same posterior distribution as would the Jeffreys Prior.  Observe that when $Z = 1$, $Z^2 = 1$, so $\tilde n = n + 1$ and $\tilde p = \frac {X + .5} {n + 1}$.

Question #2:
In general, the prior should not change based on the sample size.  The prior should reflect all the information that is known before any information has been observed.  Whether a small or large amount of data will be observed, the prior knowledge remains the same.

Comment: In regards to Question #1, the question is what are the Beta distribution shape parameters to match Agresti Coull rather than what Agresti Coull parameters to match Jeffrey's Prior.  I still awarded an up vote however because what you wrote is insightful.